# Gon variable not passing to js from rails controller during Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to create a jackpot betting site (just as a challenge). I have a method in my controller to update the pot when a user adds money to the pot. I display the pot total on the homepage and would like to update it with Ajax as soon as someone adds money to the pot. I'm using the gon gem to pass variables such as the pot total from my controller to my javascript. It works when the page is reloaded but not when the update method is called with ajax.

Heres my PagesController:

```
def home
  @jackpot = Jackpot.last
  gon.pot = @jackpot.pot
end
```

JackpotsController:

```
def update
  @jackpot = Jackpot.find(params[:id])
  if params.has_key?(:amount)
    @jackpot.update(pot: @jackpot.pot + params[:amount].to_f)
    gon.pot = @jackpot.pot
  end
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.js
  end
end
```

Javascript: (In the url the :id is hardcoded for now)

```
$("#bet-btn").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/jackpot/update/21",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function() {
          console.log("Pot size: " + gon.pot);
          updatePot();
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("error")
        }
    });
```

});

This updates the donut progress bar for the pot

```
function updatePot() {
  updateDonutChart('#jackpot-donut', gon.pot , true); 
}
```

Button to place bet: (amount also hardcoded)

```
 <%= link_to "Place Bet", update_pot_path(@jackpot, :amount => 
 0.1), method: :post,:remote => true, id: "bet-btn", class: "btn btn-info btn-lg" %>
```

I'm pretty new to rails and especially javascript/ajax so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does `console.log("Pot size: " + gon.pot);` behave as expected by displaying the updated pot value? Also in developer console do you have any errors?

Comment: @abax no, it displays the old gon.pot (current but not updated). When the page is refreshed and the ajax request is submitted again it displays the new value. This is (i think) because gon.pot is set in the pages#home action.

Comment: Maybe try using `gon.watch`,https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-gon-watch

Comment: How attached are you to **gon**? You could simply return JSON with the updated amount and read it on the success callback of your `$.ajax`.

Comment: @Leito not attached at all. Trying it because nothing else has worked for me. How would I return the JSON to the ajax callback? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, simply respond to JSON:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: { pot: @jackpot.pot } }
end
```

Specify the dataType when posting with `$.ajax`. Notice that the new data is bieng passed to the success function, so it's not `gon.pot`, but `data.pot`.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('pot', data.pot);
  }
});
```

Comment: Happy to help! Consider returning the entire @jackpot (or all that its relevant to the page) and building the json object using something more robust: JBuilder, Active Model Serializers, etc.